# ion-item / ion-native background color

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I'm getting an issue with ion-item background color.

**What I want :**

Set the background color to ***transparent.***

**What I have :**

```
<ion-item class="custom-ion-toggle">
    <ion-label>Remember me!</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle formControlName="remember" slot="start" color="secondary" mode="ios"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

This generate a `<div class="item-native">` with a white background.

**What I've tried to do :**

app.component.scss :

```
.item-native {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

**So this is what I get :**

[image]

Comment: I also tried : global.scss :

`.custom {
    &-ion-toggle {
        .item-native {
            background: transparent !important;
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 4):

try this in your css page :

```
ion-item {
  --ion-background-color: transparent !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in login.scss

```
 .custom-ion-toggle{
       background-color: transparent !important;
   }
```

i have tried it in my app and it's working completely fine.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. In fact, it change the `ion-item` background, but it's already set to `transparent`. The tag I have to manipulate is `div class="item-native">`, but I can't manipulate it's CSS properties ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the ion-item CSS custom property supplied by Ionic:

```
.custom-ion-toggle {
  --background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your css style:

```
ion-item {
 --background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Ionic 6:**

Set color property to item:

```
<ion-item color="primary">
```

In global.scss override the color:

```
ion-item {
    --ion-color-primary: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just set the property color to "undefined" in the ion-item tag and it works, give it a try.
(Also I set lines to none in ion-list to remove lines at the bottom of each item)

```
<ion-list lines="none">
  <ion-item color="undefined">
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
      <img [src]="student.photo" />
    </ion-avatar>

    <ion-label>
      <p>{{student.name}}</p>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score -2):

use ion-list instead of ion-item it will solve the problem